# Fastest wireless communication

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, communication

Hy guys,

I am currently working on a quadcopter stabilization algorithm for an indoor quadcopter. I now need to setup a wireless communication between my onboard Arduino and my controlling Arduino (and/or RasperryPi (not shure yet)).

My question is: What would be the fastest wireless communication possibility?

I am not worrying about distance; they won't get far apart from eachother. I want to keep a lot of resources on the stabilization algorithm and to keep down resources used for the communication and thus get the fastest communication on very few resources.

What are your opinions and experiences, what is going to be fastest?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between Wifi and Wireless. Wifi requires an already established network and uses the standard internet protocols. If this is what you mean, then the communication speed would only be influenced by the bandwidth of your network and the speed of the arduinos. I have not been able to find what the speeds of the modules are, but if they are 150 mB/s and your network is only 100, then you'll only get a speed of 100mB/s (which is a pretty decent speed).

If you want wireless (they create their own network using the unlicensed 2.4ghz spectrum, then buy these: nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz. They seem pretty reliable at short distances, and have a low power and high power variant. These have a speed of (at tops) 2 mB/s, but you won't have to worry about having a Wifi connection.

I personally do not know much about Bluetooth modules, so I cannot comment there.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Be careful of the distinction between *throughput* vs *latency*.  WIFI may have great throughput, but what the poster's application requires is to move a small amount of data with low latency, and simpler schemes often do better at that.  nRF24L01+ and compatible are already in widespread use as one of the three main chipsets for manual control of flying toys, so do seem worth investigating.

Comment: Good point Chris, typically a packet has to move from the quadcopter to a router and then to your PC/phone. Which might take longer as a direct link. But you should specify requirements, otherwise it will be a witchhunt on the fastest method. Also,  it's realtime and shouldn't have random  delay spikes.